# Google Sheets – Query for a date returns no values

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

​​I'm trying to filter a list from another sheet by the dates of the entries and simply doesn't work:

```
=QUERY(Import!A:Z;"select A,T where T >= date '2021-08-27'";0)
```

​When I remove the `date` part it works fine, as expexted for filtering by text. I need the ability to sort by exact dates though, because I would like to add some more complex filters. When I set the last part of the function to a `0` instead of a `1` it shows only the first entry.

The source column is set to the correct date format. The data is pulled from another document using the `IMPORTRANGE()`​ function (I don't seee how this should make any difference though).

I feel like I'm misssing something simple here and would be glad if someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Try to format the column T in number for instance. If nothing change, that means that your dates are string. In that situation you need first to tranform string to date. Check also if there no mix between texts and numbers in columns, query doesn't work properly with mixed data. Mayb share a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: There are many things that could be the problem here. Without seeing the spreadsheet, it's like calling a mechanic and saying, "Hey, my car is making a weird noise. I can't bring it in to you, but what's wrong with it and how do I fix it?" I invite you to share a link to the spreadsheet, so that the volunteer contributors here can see all of the pieces of information that you may not be looking for yourself.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: I would love to share a sample but unfortunately my organisation prohibits me from doing so. I cannot even access the blank sheet that I've tried to generate.

The entries are formatted as dates and `=isdate(import!T2)​` returns ​`TRUE​`. However, I have noticed that a small number of cells don't contain dates but only an en-dash. I feel like I'm onto something here...

Answer (score 1):

Check your date column if all cells are formatted as date. I had missing values as "='---" and the query filtering by date returned nothing. Changing the missing values to "=NA()" did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(Import!A:Z;"select A,T where T >= date '"&TEXT("2021-08-27";"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Comment: Hey, Vladimir thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it doesn't appear to work in my case because a small number of cells don't contain dates but only an en-dash. Therefore they are not recognised as dates, resulting in an empty value arror. Do you happen to know a way to deal with this?